# how to use ENUM in another c# file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, unityscript

I defined a enum type in **Stone.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public enum ColliderType { ColliderTypeSlowDown,ColliderTypeLoseControl };

public class Stone : MonoBehaviour {
    public ColliderType colliderType;

    void Start () {
    }

    void Update () {
    }
}
```

And Then I want to use it in **PlayerControl.cs**

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider obstacle)  
    {  
        if (obstacle.CompareTag("Stone"))  
        {  
            Stone stone = obstacle.gameObject.GetComponent ();
            if (stone.colliderType == ColloderTypeSlowDown) {
             // code
            }
            else  {
            // code
            }
        }  
    }
```

And it thrown an mistake : **The name 'ColliderTypeSlowDown' does not exist in the current context.**
I am a objective-c coder.I tried many times but can not fix it out . How should I fix this?

Comment: include the namespace: `using Stone;`

Answer (score 1):

Oh，sorry, It's a simple question. I read someone else's code and I know why .

```
if (stone.colliderType == ColliderType.ColliderTypeSlowDown) {
}
```

**ColliderType.ColliderTypeSlowDown** but not **ColliderTypeSlowDown**